# Questions about mysql json_extract()

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hello i have a question about mysql json_extract function.

there are two tables;

```
users
+------------------------------------+
|   id  |  email                     |
+------------------------------------+
|   1   |  red@google.com            |      
+------------------------------------+
|   2   |  green@google.com          |      
+------------------------------------+

room
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   id  |  invited(json type)                                                      |                                          
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |  {"invite": [{"To": "red@google.com"}, {"To": "green@google.com"}]}    
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i want to get invited users from room table.
so i tried

```
SELECT A.id, A.email
FROM users A JOIN room B ON 
(A.email = json_extract(B.invited,'$.invite[*].To')
```

but json_extract() return

```
["red@google.com", "green@google.com"]
```

If I use 'json_extract(B.invited,'$.invite[0].To')'
 it is possible to get one. but can't get several users.

is there any possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `JSON_CONTAINS`. It should be something like that:

```
SELECT A.id, A.email
FROM users A
JOIN room B 
  ON json_contains(json_extract(B.invited,'$.invite[*].To'), json_quote(A.email))
```